# integral transition

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am studying about length of curve called Cardioid and there is one transition i don't understand:

$$2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{a^2(1+\cos{\phi})^2+a^2(\sin{\phi})^2}d\phi=8a\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}d\phi}$$

Comment: Expand the expression under the radical and apply a half-angle trig identities.

Comment: I get $$\sqrt{2}a \sqrt{1+\cos{\phi}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may notice that
$$
2\cos^2 \frac{\phi}2=1+\cos{\phi}, \quad \sin{\phi}=2\sin \frac{\phi}2\cos \frac{\phi}2
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
2\int_0^\pi\sqrt{a^2(1+\cos{\phi})^2+a^2(\sin{\phi})^2}\:d\phi&=2a\int_0^\pi\sqrt{4\left(\cos^2 \frac{\phi}2+\sin^2 \frac{\phi}2\right)\cos^2 \frac{\phi}2}\:d\phi
\\\\&=4a\int_0^\pi\cos \frac{\phi}2\:d\phi
\\\\&=4a\int_0^\pi\sin \frac{\phi}2\:d\phi.
\\\\&=8a.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How does my book get $8|a|$

Comment: https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/nastava/analiza/files/ch2_7.pdf page 80 bottom

Comment: @RushThaMan There is a misprint in the next-to-final step in the book. That 8 should be a 4. But the integral of $\sin(\phi/2)$ from $0$ to $\pi$ equals $2$, so in the end, the result is $8a$.

Comment: The final result in the book is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
2\int_0^\pi\sqrt{a^2(1+\cos(\phi))^2+a^2(\sin(\phi))^2}\,\mathrm{d}\phi
&=4a\int_0^\pi\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\phi)}2}\,\mathrm{d}\phi\\
&=4a\int_0^\pi\cos\left(\frac\phi2\right)\,\mathrm{d}\phi\\
&=8a\left[\sin\left(\frac\phi2\right)\right]_0^{\pi}\\
\end{align}
$$